# In react js home page stays rendered when switching to new page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-development-server

When I press the button inside button container 1, the page changes but the contents of the previous page stays rendered. How can I fix this issue?

```
function App() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  return (
    <div className="background-video">
      <video autoPlay muted loop>
        <source src={bgvideo} type="video/mp4" />
        console.log("okok");
      </video>
      <div className="logo">
        <img src={logo} alt="Logo" />
      </div>
      <div className="button-container1">
        <button onClick={() => navigate("/stats")}>
          See your Listening Stats
        </button>
      </div>
      <div className="button-container2">
        <button>Generate a Playlist</button>
      </div>
      <div className="button-container3">
        <button>Realtime Friends Playlist</button>
      </div>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" />
        <Route path="/stats" element={<Stats />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Which content are you talking about? The video for example?

Comment: yes the video and the buttons

Answer (score 0):

You are rendering your Routes in the same component as the content. Move your content inside another component and add that component as “element” to the route route.